# Bind Treeview to data structure

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview, bind

I have the following class definition where I want to bind it to a Treeview in WPF if possible. Not sure where to start on this one. Any clues?

```
public class DirectoryTree
{
    public String Name {get; set;}

    public String FullPath { get; set; }

    public List<DirectoryTree> Children { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Would you pls take a look at below link **Josh Smiths excellent tutorial**, I hope it will helps you http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all right with your code. All you need is to define HierarchicalDataTemplate for TreeView and may be add two properties to DirectoryTree - IsSelected and IsExpanded - using INotifyPropertyChanged.